# Calculate CRC for the message

Tags: networking, crc, redundancy

```
Message= 1010001101
The CRC for this msg using the divisor polynomial x^5 + x^4 + x^2 +1 is?
```

I am getting it to be `01110` but in the book the answer given is `10101`.

Please show how `"10101"` could be the CRC for the given message.

Comment: No, please show your code so we can comment.

Comment: Thanks @EJP for your response. I didn't haven't done it with code. I have just divided the message "101000110100000" with the crc generator 110101 to check the remainder. And it comes to be 01110 but according to the book the correct CRC is "10101". So, I am a bit confused if I made any mistake or missed and in depth concept of CRC.

Comment: The answer you found is right! Good job!

Comment: If there is no code the question is off-topic for this site, but you should have read in your book that the highest bit in the polynomial is only conceptual and doesn't take part in the actual calculation.